# Generate all one step variations of a permutation

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I was just wondering whether there was a more dynamic way of getting one step variations from a given permutation rather than specifying each and every step. What I plan on doing is if I have lets say a permutation of "(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,)" and I specify a possibility of choices to choose from as a range so in this case I specified the range to be 5 and the choices would be "0,1,2,3,4" and I want to generate permutations that look like: (1,0,0,0,0) , (2,0,0,0,0), (3,0,0,0,0) and so on where you can only change one element at a time how would I do that. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely sure what you are looking for... Maybe something like this,

```
def single_element_permutation(given, new):
    for i in xrange(len(given)):
        for ele in new:
            yield given[:i] + (ele,) + given[i+1:]

for e in single_element_permutation((0, 0, 0, 0, 0), range(5)):
    print e
```

Output:

```
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(3, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(4, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 2, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 3, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 4, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 2, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 3, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 4, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 2, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 3, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 4, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for p in product(range(5), repeat=5):
    print(p[::-1])
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(3, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(4, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
(1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
....
>>> import itertools
>>> for p in itertools.permutations(range(5)):
    print(p[::-1])
(4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
(3, 4, 2, 1, 0)
(4, 2, 3, 1, 0)
(2, 4, 3, 1, 0)
(3, 2, 4, 1, 0)
....
>>> for p in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(5), 5):
    print(p)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 4)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
....
```

Like that? Something along those lines?? :P